# Excel SUMIFS based on two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to total a list of minutes based on two criteria to make a graph after the data is calculated.

The item "Department" (Column C) and "Day of Week" (Column F) are both drop down menus.

I would like to calculate the total number of labor minutes (Column E)  for the "HMX" selection in Column C on "Monday" in Column F.

Right now, I have been successful using the `SUMIFS` function to calculate based on one criteria using the formula:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E40, C2:C40, "HMX")
```

Is there a way to alter this to include the second set of criteria?

Or is there another way to achieve the result I described?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another criteria to [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) by adding additional parameters.

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E40, C2:C40, "HMX", E2:E40, "Monday")
```